# How to add our custom library to Apache Spark?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, distributed-computing

I want to add GeoSpark library to Apache Spark. How do I add GeoSpark library from Spark shell?

Comment: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#using-the-shell

Comment: There is a good thread about the same topic here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132559/add-jars-to-a-spark-job-spark-submit

Answer (score 3):

```
$ ./bin/spark-shell --master local[4] --jars code.jar
```

--jars option will distribute your local custom jar to cluster automatically.