# Java application on Apache Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

Could anybody tell me if any Java application can be deployed on Apache Spark or any criteria (code modification,..) must be taken into account?

Comment: like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367085/how-to-add-our-custom-library-to-apache-spark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import/run any java libraries in your spark application. You can start your spark application through Java api or scala api.

Spark has its own programming model, you have to follow that and add extra things you like

Comment: Thanks @Grant, so, if I have my own .jar then I could create a spark application through Java api which instances my .jar?

Comment: Yes or No. You will build a fat jar which contains all of the dependencies of your application. Your own jar(or its contents) will be assembled into the final fat jar. Just think of your jar as the dependency